# Example of a non-injective bounded linear operator whose range is not closed but dense.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

> What are some concrete examples of non-injective bounded linear operators defined on a Hilbert space whose kernels are infinite dimensional and whose ranges are not closed but dense?

Any help will be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Define $T_1 \in \mathcal L \left (\ell^2 (\mathbb N) \right )$ as follows $:$ $$T_1 e_n = \begin{cases} e_{\frac {n} {2}} & n\ \text {even} \\ 0 & n\ \text {odd} \end{cases}$$ and define $T_2 \in \mathcal L \left (L^2[0,1] \right )$ by $T_2 : = M_x$ where $M_x$ is the multiplication by $x \mapsto x.$ Now take the direct sum $T = T_1 \oplus T_2$ on $\mathcal H = \ell^2 (\mathbb N) \oplus L^2[0,1].$

Answer (score 2):

Fix a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$.

To get an infinite-dimensional kernel, we split the basis in $\{e_{2n}\}$ and $\{e_{2n-1}\}$. Then we make $T$ act only on the "even", guaranteeing that $e_{2n-1}\in\ker T$ for all $n$.

If we were to define $Te_{2n}=e_n$, then $T$ would be a co-isometry, and it would be surjective. So we can define
$$
Te_{2n}=\tfrac1n\,e_n.
$$
Then the range of $T$ contains all $e_n$, so it is certainly dense. But it cannot be everything, since $T$ is compact. Or, explicitly, you can check that
$$
x=\sum_n\tfrac1n\,e_n
$$
is not in the range of $T$.

In the end, you can take $T$ as the linear operator induced by
$$
Te_n=\begin{cases}
\tfrac2n\,e_{n/2},&\ n\ \text{ even }\\[0.3cm] 0,&\ n\ \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
The coefficients $2/n$ can be replaced by any sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ of complex such that $\apha_n\to0$, and the example works the same.